# Are there any good open source examples of JRuby + Clojure integration?

Tags: clojure, jruby

Are there any open source projects that use both JRuby and Clojure and integrate the two parts somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never used these projects, but they should give you a starting point:

https://github.com/stilkov/jruby-rails-clojure

https://github.com/technomancy/clojure-gem

Answer (score 0):

The [AltLaw](http://altlaw.org/) project (2007-2010) used JRuby and Clojure.

- [Example Clojure code calling JRuby](https://github.com/stuartsierra/altlaw-backend/blob/master/src/org/altlaw/util/jruby.clj)

Answer (score 0):

I [added a Clojure REPL](http://redcareditor.com/blog/2010/08/redcar-039/) to [Redcar Editor](http://redcareditor.com/).  It was a pretty painless process and worked just as you would expect.  The [source code](https://github.com/danlucraft/redcar/tree/master/plugins/clojure) is available on GitHub.